# What is going on here? Omnibus repeated measures ANOVA is marginal, but follow-up planned pairs <.05

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, assumptions, reporting

I have a repeated measure ANOVA with a decent sample size (124 participants, with a score for each person for 3 conditions). The data are moderate to strongly positively skewed, (though similarly). Sphericity looks fine.
I realize that my statistics professor was old school and always had us do protected tests, but I thought that there could not be a conflict like this (if the omnibus F is not significant, that meant that no pairs would show as significantly different). I'm just going to report non-parametric tests, but I'm just trying to get a conceptual hold of what's going on here. Is this because of the skew, or am I potentially missing something?

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not asking IF that can happen (which is covered elsewhere on the site) I'm asking in what kind of situations/why this happens.

Comment: I have found enough of an answer elsewhere on this site (after a lot of looking however). May I ask how I delete this question so it doesn't spam thing up for others?

Comment: If you look under your post, just below the tags and above these comments, some distance to the left of your gravatar, you should see a set of clickable links, something like "share edit close delete flag", (though possibly you might not see some of these). Click the one that says "delete"

Comment: Sorry all, I just have share, edit, flag. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Then click `flag` and explain that you want to delete it.

Comment: where did you find the answer? I am having the same problen